# intercept html5 number input before rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to intercept input change events before the value is rendered to the screen.  This would be useful for prepending zeroes.  However, this is not working.

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="tc" type="number" value="100"></input>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#tc").on( 'change', function() {
  $("#tc").val( "12" );
})
</script>
</html>
```

Neither is listening on requestAnimationFrame and changing the value.  What do do?

Fwiw, this works in Safari (but not Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe on `keydown`.

```
$("#tc").on( 'keydown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#tc").val( "12" );
});
```

Or if you want from all the input sources subscribe for `input`:

```
$("#tc").on( 'input', function(event) {
  $("#tc").val( "12" );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the value with `$("#tc").val( "12" );` and use `.on('change')` when they change the value.

```
$("#tc").val( "0.00" );
$("#tc").on( 'change', function() {
    var n = $(this).val()
    $("#tc").val(n + ".00" );
});
```

Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdvQY/) example